# Python: how to make a nested list of depth n?

Tags: python, list, nested-lists

I want to make a list of list of list... of depth n.

Curently, I use:

```
a = []
for i in range(n - 1):
    a = [a]
print a
```

For example, if `n = 3` i got `[[[ ]]]`.

Is it a clearest and more pythonic way to do this?

Comment: True! I don't think that is quite useful to have more pythonic way to do this. I mean who wanna create list with depth n, everyday in his code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I think you've already got the best way. It's faster and doesn't suffer the limits mentioned by @Aleksi

Alternative would be to write a recursive function or use eval

```
eval('['*n + ']'*n)  # much slower than a for loop!
```

Comment: The eval version breaks at 100, though. (And same problem for recursive at the recursion limit, obviously)

Comment: @AleksiTorhamo, yes, good point! I'd only use it for something quick in the REPL anyway

Answer (score 0):

Is this *Pythonic* enough?

```
>>> n = 5
>>> map(lambda i: (lambda f, *a: f(f, [], *a))(lambda rec, k, i: k if i == 2 else rec(rec, [k], i-1), i), [n])
[[[[[]]]]]
```